# Dynamic Nested or MultiDimensional Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

I wanted to implement a nested NSMutableArray in my XML data. The Array is structures like this,

```
NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: sub_name, sub_desc, sub_imageLink, nil];
NSMutableArray *myArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *)name, (NSString *)desc, (NSString *)imageLink, subArray,nil],
                          [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *)name, (NSString *)desc, (NSString *)imageLink, subArray,nil],
                          [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *)name, (NSString *)desc, (NSString *)imageLink, subArray,nil], nil];
```

the XML is like this,

```
<category>
        <name>Drinks</name>
        <description>Drink description</description>
        <image> Link Here </image>
            <sub_cat>
                <sub_name>Sub name of Drink</sub_name>
                <sub_desc>sub description of Drink</sub_desc>
                <sub_image>Sub Link of Drink </sub_image>
            </sub_cat>
            <sub_cat>
                <sub_name>Sub name of Drink</sub_name>
                <sub_desc>sub description of Drink</sub_desc>
                <sub_image>Sub Link of Drink </sub_image>
            </sub_cat>
</category>
```

Im trying this to implement in didStartElement and didEndElement, and Im really confuse and so lost in this, been cracking my head for about a week now too. Would really appreciate some suggestions.

How would i implement TBXML for this given XML or for GData implementation, i really need a quick sample, im a beginner at this one thats why Im needing someone to guide me in the right way.

Comment: Dimen ***SSSSSSS*** ional...

Comment: There are a few great XML parsing libraries out there. Better not to reinvent the wheel. For what it's worth, trying to successfully use NSXMLParser without headaches is a pain in the ______.

Comment: So you want to parse it with a SAX parser ? I recommend you to have a look at a DOM parser, it will be much easier to do.

Here is a great link from ray wenderlich.

[how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Regards

Comment: Im really new about this parsing and stuff, and Im just parsing the XML using NSXMLParser if thats what u want to know. And now Im trying to find a way on how am i able to parse that XML and show its child element when I click on their parent attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) tutorial about how to read and write xml file in ios. It uses `GDataXML` library to read/write xml file. All steps are give about how to use that library in your existing project. Always try to parse XML file by using libraries, they prevent us from lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use this nice library for XML parsing : [TBXML](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)